# Adding taxonomy term list to another taxonomy term's overview

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Let me start by saying I'm fairly new to Drupal. I'm using Drupal 7.

I have a content type "product" which is assigned to one or more taxonomy terms in "collections" (taxonomy). Then I have another taxonomy called "brands".

The "brands" taxonomy has a field reference to a "collections" taxonomy term. For instance: brand "Google" can be assigned to collections "Shoes" or "Bags".

On the collection page for "Shoes", all the products tagged "Shoes" are being displayed. On top of the page, I want to add a list of all the brands in the "brands" taxonomy, that are assigned to this particular collection ("Shoes"). They are independent from the products themselves. How would I display this list on top of the page? Do I need to create a custom overview?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to a create view that displays block on top of the collection page.
The view should display taxonomy terms in the "collections" vocabulary filtered by a contextual filter (taxonomy term id) so that only the desired taxonomy term is display.
Next you should add a relationship using the field reference you're using on that term.
Finally you can use the relationship to display fields or taxonomy terms to the display.

I tried to explain it briefly, let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I understand correctly, I need to create a view for displaying the brand list on top of the collection page? This is independent from the collection page itself? How do I add this relationship?

Comment: I hope this article helps you out: http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-sense-drupal-views-relationships-and-entity-references

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look at it, and accept your answer as soon as I know for sure it was the right one :)